# Pivot and sum with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a query that creates the following data:

```
ID          LegacyID                type1 type2 date        value
1500000001  10070242801000000217    DF    RN    2018-05-24  -3.33000000
1500000002  10078387921000000217    PP    IN    2018-05-26  -11.00000000
1500000002  10078387921000000217    PP    RN    2018-05-26  -100.00000000
1500000003  10080625841000000217    DF    RN    2018-05-23  -3.33000000
1500000003  10080625841000000217    DF    RN    2018-05-23  99.000000
```

I'm trying to pivot the data on the type fields, summing the value while grouping by the ID, LegacyID and date fields.

Creating this:

```
id              legacyid                    date        DFRN          PPIN          PPRN
1500000001      10070242801000000217        2018-05-24  -3.33000000   0             0
1500000002      10078387921000000217        2018-05-26  0            -11.00000000   -100.00000000
1500000003      10080625841000000217        2018-05-23  95.67000000   0             0
```

Notice that i'm trying to concatenate the type fields into their unique combinations.

I've tried several mutations of pivot, but I cant seem to get it right, my latest attempt (that doesnt work) looks like this:

```
    select
        id,
        legacyid,
        [date],
        [DF]+[RN] as DFRN,
        [CR]+[CR] as CRCR,
        [CR]+[MR] as CRMR,
        [DF]+[DS] as DFDS,
        [DF]+[MR] as DFMR,
        [PP]+[DS] as PPDS,
        [PP]+[IN] as PPIN,
        [PP]+[RN] as PPRN,
    from (
    select
        tl.[id],
        r.[LegacyId],
        a.type1,
        bt.type2,   
        [Date],
        gl.TotalAmountUSD as [value]
    from
       ----long join
    where
        gh.IsActive = 1                             
    group by 
        tl.id,
        r.LegacyId,
        a.type1,
        bt.type2,
        [date])
    ) as bb
    pivot
    (
        sum(value)
        for rentalid in (
        [DF]+[RN] as DFRN,
        [CR]+[CR] as CRCR,
        [CR]+[MR] as CRMR,
        [DF]+[DS] as DFDS,
        [DF]+[MR] as DFMR,
        [PP]+[DS] as PPDS,
        [PP]+[IN] as PPIN,
        [PP]+[RN] as PPRN)
    ) as p
```

How would one pivot on this?

Comment: Have you tried concatenating type1+type2 in your derived table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
with t as (
      . . .
     )
select ID, LegacyID, date,
       sum(case when type1 = 'DF' and type2 = 'RN' then value end) as DFRN,
       sum(case when type1 = 'PP' and type2 = 'IN' then value end) as PPIN,
       sum(case when type1 = 'PP' and type2 = 'RN' then value end) as PPRN
from t
group by ID, LegacyID, date ;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, as usual its a pleasure being schooled by you.